# I want to only (physically) print the content of my div with contenteditable="true"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on an assignment for University, and I want to create a Rich Text Editor using HTML, CSS and JS.
I am using the MIDAS API and I know it is not recommended to use it but it's only for a short term project.
My problem is with printing the content of my div since it always appears where my div is situated and not on the top of my page.
Requested Solution: A way to print only the content of the contenteditable div or a way to move it to the top of the page.

**HTML**

```html
<button class="fa fa-print" onclick="printtext()"></button>
<div id="editor1" class="border1" contenteditable="true" style="min-height:10em; padding:1em;">
</div>
```

**JS**

```js
function printtext() {
    window.print();
}
```

**CSS**

```css
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    body {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #editor1 {
        visibility: visible;
        border: none !important;
    }

    @page { size: auto;  margin: 0; }
</style>
```

Comment: `visibiliy: hidden` only hides the elements. Use `display:none` instead to remove the elements from the DOM completely.

Answer (score 1):

Funny enough when i was creating this question, the bulb in my head lit.
I added these 3 lines to my CSS.

**CSS**

```css
#editor1 {
    visibility: visible;
    border: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 5em;
}
```